# Copy to clipboard functionality in javascript?

Tags: javascript

i have button functions for copy to clipboard, on clicking on the button, the page getting Refreshed automatically. But, i don't want the page to be refreshed with Internet Explorer it's possible using

```
 event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
```

This code is working fine in IE. Is there a similar way in Firefox and Chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a button,

```
  <button class="SmallBtn" type="button" onclick="Print()" id="BatchDetailPrintBtn">Print</button>
```

jquery looks like

```
 function Print() {
window.print();
}
```

This works perfect for me.